# How to use a non-adafruit BMP280 sensor for continuous data outflow

Tags: arduino-nano

please I need help with the arduino BMP280 breakout board I got from  AliExpress. I’m pretty new to the arduino world, I need it for my rocket datalogger, I downloaded the adafruit BMP280 library but I don’t know how or where to change the data rate and what does the “default standby time” mean in the library sensor code? I want to get at least 10-20points of data per second as the rocket will be traveling very fast. Can someone please help me with a solution, or if there’s another library that solves my problem. I’m really stuck. Also, I don’t want my code to stop while waiting for temp, pressure and altitude values and also get the altitude before launch so that I can now the approximate height of the rocket above see level. Any help would be appreciated.

Details
Connection type: 12c
Application : Water rocket altimeter/datalogger and flightcomputer.

Brand: Unknown
Microcontroller: Arduino Nano

Comment: you said nothing about what you have ... you only described what you want to use it for ... please provide a link to the datasheet for the device

Comment: Show what you've done so far in getting the altitude from the pressure reading, and what stop you from reading it multiple times?

Comment: Take a look at the source code of Adafruit [library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BMP280_Library/blob/master/Adafruit_BMP280.h#L166)

Comment: With a single instantaneous pressure reading you can't get sea-level and elevation. You need to know sea-level to get elevation. You need to know elevation to get sea-level. You can get a "flight level" by setting the sea-level pressure to 1013.25hPa but that's only a true elevation on a very small number of days in the year (if any). So you need to work out how you're going to set the MSL value for your altimeter before flight. You really need to post the code that you've tried so far.